# Which Java CMS can communicate with EJBs deployed on the same application server?

Tags: java, jboss, content-management-system, opencms, magnolia

I already asked this question over at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/196949/), but perhaps it's better to ask here.

We developed a JavaEE6 application. This application is basically something similar like a backend to a webshop (no user interface at all, just calculations/data handling). Now, we're looking for a web CMS with which we can use this backend. So, basically just a web CMS which is user-friendly to the end-user who can then change static page contents using the web CMS, and which we can program to use our backend for doing some calculations. JSF wound be nice ...

So I'm asking for suggestions on which web CMS to use, and on how to do the integration. If more clarifications are needed, I'll try to provide them.

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've integrated SpringMVC with OpenCms. I guess it would also be working with EJB.

http://www.sendspace.com/file/x2sipm

but I would also take a look at Magnolia in parallel, which @lutzh recommended below, it's also a good java-based CMS actually. I guess both will work fine with EJB, so in the end it's just a matter of taste / other criterias, which of those CMS you prefer (feature-wise, UI-wise, etc.).

Comment: Hi Mathias, the link does not work anymore. Do you have an updated link?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with Magnolia CMS, especially with the Blossom Module you get a pretty clean MVC architecture. Have the Spring controller handle the calls to you EJB server, then render the view with Magnolia (mixing content from the repository with the data from your EJB server).
I don't think JSF is supported as a view technology, though. Freemarker or JSP.